# hidden setting icon of start menu on windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, startmenu

I've got a Windows Mobile 5 and i need to hide settings icon

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN2I8.png]

We have employees that don't speak English, and I need the desktop to be very simplified. I just need hide the icon settings beacause got configuration that they cant to move

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/10/19/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-clear-today-and-programs/) is an application including source code to hide elements from the home screen.

You have to look at the registry at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Today\Items and set Enabled=0 for the items that should not be shown.

The settings icon is controlled separately by HKLM\Security\Shell\StartInfo:HideSettings registry key.

Although you can hide the settings icon, the user can still access settings using the top bar! To prohibit that you need to code more. See my KIOSK articles at my web blog above.

Comment: thaks that is look for, but how can i acccess to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Today\Items

Comment: You can use any registry editor that supports windows mobile. In example the RemoteRegistryEditor coming with Visual Studio, Tascal RegEdit (running on device), use a wap provisioning xml file, use CeRegeditor or any other supported. How to change the registry of a windows mobile device is a totally different question.